# Как исправить ошибки при установки SQL server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server

После запуска мастера установки sql Server сама установка не запускается
В логах две ошибки:

```
Error: Action "PostMsiTimingConfigAction" failed during execution.
```

`Error: Action "PreMsiTimingConfigAction" failed during execution`.

Предыдущий SQL Server удалили, реест почистил, но поведение одно и тоже.
Может кто-то сталкивался?

Видео с проблемой:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tKU3CsXBClNMRfSk3ZnkBFv50cteGMr2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Это смотрели? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f04d570a-4baf-4773-99b5-8b641434a5d4/sql-server-2012-developer-edition-will-not-install-setup-files-dont-even-get-copied-completely?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Так точно! Пробовал делать ISO образ разархивировал и перенес на диск С от туда запускаю установку и поведение такое же